# Binary Search Tree no matching function call

Tags: c++

I tried programming a binary search tree in c++ with a constructor for the null node that inserts the main array into it and prints the result, at least that was the intention.  I'm getting these two errors and need to correct them to the specifications, if possible, as stated.  What needs to be done is to create a node_t * constructor and insert the array into the binary search tree.
error: no matching function for call to 'BST::insert(BST&, std::array::value_type&)'
error: no matching function for call to 'BST::print_bst(BST&)'

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

/*
 * Define a node structure for double linked list.
 */
class BST 
{
private:
    typedef struct node {
        int val;
        struct node* left;
        struct node* right;
    } node_t;
    node_t* tree;

public:
    BST() { tree = NULL; }
    node_t* newNode(int val);
    node_t* insert(node_t* cur_root, int val);
    node_t* find_node(int val, node_t* root);
    node_t* find_val(int val, node_t* root);
    node_t* delete_node(int val, node_t* root);
    void delete_bst(node_t* root);
    void print_bst(node_t* root);
    node_t* find_max(node_t* root);
};

// Creates a new node from a given value, allocating heap memory 
// for it.
BST::node_t* BST::newNode(int val)
{
    node_t* newNode = new node;
    newNode->val = val;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

// Inserts a new value into a given binary search tree, 
// allocating heap memory for it.
BST::node_t* BST::insert(BST::node_t* cur_root, int val)
{
     if(cur_root == NULL) { return newNode(val); }
     if( val <= cur_root->val )
         cur_root->left = insert(cur_root->left, val);
     else if( val > cur_root->val)
         cur_root->right = insert(cur_root->right, val);
     return cur_root;
}

BST::node_t* BST::find_node(int val, BST::node_t* root) {
    if (root == NULL || root->val == val) { return root; }
    else if (root->val <= val) { 
        return find_node( val, root->left );
    }
    else { return find_node( val, root->right ); }
    return root;
}

BST::node_t* BST::find_max(BST::node_t* root)
{
    if(root ==  NULL)
    return NULL;
    while(root->right != NULL)
    {
        root = root->right;
    }
    return root;
}

// Deletes node and reorders bst
BST::node_t* BST::delete_node(int val, BST::node_t* root)   
{
    if( root == NULL ) return root;
    else if( val <= root->val )
        root->left = delete_node( val, root->left );
    else if( val > root->val )
        root->right = delete_node( val, root->right );
    else
    {
        // No child
        if( root->right == NULL && root->left == NULL )
        {
            delete root;
            root = NULL;
        }
        // One child
        else if(root->right == NULL)
        {
            node_t* temp = root;
            root = root->left;
            delete temp;
        }
        else if( root->left == NULL )
        {
            node_t* temp = root;
            root = root->right;
            delete temp;
        }
        // Two child
        else
        {
            node_t* temp = find_max(root->left);
            root->val = temp->val;
            root->left = delete_node(temp->val, root->left);
        }
    }
    return root;
}

// Given a pointer to the root, frees the memory associated with 
// an entire tree.
void BST::delete_bst(BST::node_t* root) {
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        delete_bst( root->left );
        delete_bst( root->right );
        delete(root);
        if( root->left != NULL)
            root->left = NULL;
        if( root->right != NULL)
            root-> right = NULL;
        root = NULL;
    }
}

/* Given a pointer to the root, prints all of
 * the values in a tree.
 */
void BST::print_bst(BST::node_t* root) 
{
    if (root != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", root->val);
        print_bst(root->left);
        print_bst(root->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    BST bst;
    array<int, 9> ai = {17, 9, 23, 5, 11, 21, 27, 20, 22};
    for( size_t i = 0; i < ai.size(); ++i)
    {
        bst.insert(bst, ai[i]);
    }
    BST::print_bst(bst);
}
```

Comment: your insert function takes node argument not BST. for print call print_bst from bst instance.  btw i cannot see any root.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'BST::insert(BST&, std::array::value_type&)'
> error: no matching function for call to 'BST::print_bst(BST&)'
> ```

The errors are telling your your calls to `insert` and `print_bst` in `main()` are wrong. Specifically, you have:

```
    for( size_t i = 0; i < ai.size(); ++i)
    {
        bst.insert(bst, ai[i]);
    }
    BST::print_bst(bst);
```

One glaring issues is `BST::print_bst(bst);`. You do not use the resolution operator here, from a syntax standpoint you want `bst.print_bst(bst);` (that is only the tip-of-the-iceberg)

You are passing both `insert` and `print_bst` the parameter `bst`, an object of type `BST` not `node_t *`. What you want to pass them is `tree`, but you can't because `tree` is *private*.

One way to handle this is write a simple accessor function to return the address of `tree` for use in the functions, e.g.

```
  public:
    ...
    node_t *get_root (void) { return tree; }    /* tree accessor */
```

Now you can call both `insert` and `print_bst` as follows:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ai.size(); i++)
        bst.insert (bst.get_root(), ai[i]);

    bst.print_bst (bst.get_root());
    putchar ('\n');       /* make your program POSIX compliant with final '\n' */
}
```

From a compilation standpoint, you should also compile with `-Wshadow` to insure you are not shadowing or attempting to redeclare variables within another scope. You have that problem here:

```
BST::node_t* BST::newNode(int val)
{
    node_t* newNode = new node;
```

`newNode` shadows your member function `newNode`, e.g.

```
  public:
    ...
    node_t* newNode(int val);
```

You can simply change the new node you declare in `newNode` to `newnode` (or anything else to not conflict with your member function). While that isn't an issue the way it is used here, it can bite you if you are not checking for shadowed names.

In your `BST` object, `tree` is the pointer to beginning of your binary tree, but you never assign the beginning of the binary tree (or anything else for that matter) to `tree`. You end up calling `insert` over and over with `cur_root == NULL` and returning `return newNode(val);` which isn't used anywhere, so the result is `cur_root` is always `NULL`. Instead, you need to check if `tree == NULL` and set `tree = newNode (val);` if it is. If you want to return the pointer just `return (tree = newNode (val));`, e.g.

```
/* Inserts a new value into a given binary search tree, 
 * allocating heap memory for it.
 */
BST::node_t *BST::insert (BST::node_t *cur_root, int val)
{
     if (tree == NULL)  /* you must assign 1st node to tree */
        return (tree = newNode(val));

     if (cur_root == NULL)
        return (cur_root = newNode(val));

     if (val <= cur_root->val )
         cur_root->left = insert (cur_root->left, val);
     else if (val > cur_root->val)
         cur_root->right = insert (cur_root->right, val);

     return cur_root;
}
```

**Note:** keep your parameter order consistent. Don't swap the order, that just makes things horribly confusing, e.g.

```
    node_t* insert(node_t* cur_root, int val);
    node_t* find_node(int val, node_t* root);
```

One way or the other. I prefer `(node_t* cur_root, int val)`, but it is up to you. If you prefer `(int val, node_t* root)`, then use that, but be consistent.

Your `BST::delete_bst` attempts to access values after you have freed them to set them to `NULL`, e.g.

```
// Given a pointer to the root, frees the memory associated with 
// an entire tree.
void BST::delete_bst(BST::node_t* root) {
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        delete_bst( root->left );
        delete_bst( root->right );
        delete(root);
        if( root->left != NULL)
            root->left = NULL;
        if( root->right != NULL)
            root-> right = NULL;
        root = NULL;
    }
}
```

By the time you get to `root->left = NULL;` and `root-> right = NULL;` and `root = NULL;`, those blocks of memory no longer exists.

Instead you can use something like the following and set `tree = NULL;` at the end,

```
/* Given a pointer to the root, frees the memory associated with 
 * an entire tree.
 */
void BST::delete_bst (BST::node_t *root)
{
    if (root != NULL) {
        delete_bst (root->left);
        delete_bst (root->right);
        delete(root);
    }

    tree = NULL;
}
```

You find these problems by using a memory error checking program like `valgrind` on Linux. (but obviously, your code must compile before you can do that). There are similar programs for every OS.

That is the bulk of you logic problem. There are cleanup issues you need to correct, like if you declare a constructor, then declare a destructor as well. If you declare either a constructor or destructor, then you should also declare a *copy-constructor* as well, see [**Rule of Three**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Also, make sure the output to your program is POSIX compliant and always provides a final `'\n'`. Otherwise, when run from a console, you end up with your prompt stuck at the end of the last line of output. You can simply tack on a `putchar ('\n');` at the end of `main()` (since you didn't include `<iostream>`) or write a simple wrapper function for `print_bst` that does it for you, e.g.

```
  public:
    ...
    void print_tree (void) { print_bst (tree); putchar ('\n'); };
```

and then you are free to call `bst.print_tree();` in `main()` and not have to worry about it.

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

/*
 * Define a node structure for a binary tree list.
 */
class BST 
{
  private:
    typedef struct node {
        int val;
        struct node* left;
        struct node* right;
    } node_t;
    node_t *tree;

  public:
    BST() { tree = NULL; }
   ~BST() { delete_bst (tree); }   /* if you define BST(), define ~BST() */
    node_t *get_root (void) { return tree; }    /* tree accessor */
    node_t *newNode (int val);
    node_t *insert (node_t* cur_root, int val);
    node_t *find_node (node_t* root, int val);
    node_t *find_val (node_t* root, int val);
    node_t *delete_node (node_t* root, int val);
    void delete_bst (node_t* root);
    void print_bst (node_t* root);
    node_t *find_max (node_t* root);
    /* make program output POSIX compliant with final '\n'
     * (just create a wrapper for print_bst, or add putchar('\n') in main )
     */
    void print_tree (void) { print_bst (tree); putchar ('\n'); };
};

/* Creates a new node from a given value, allocating heap memory for it. */
BST::node_t* BST::newNode (int val)
{
    node_t* newnode = new node_t;
    newnode->val = val;
    newnode->left = NULL;
    newnode->right = NULL;
    return newnode;
}

/* Inserts a new value into a given binary search tree, 
 * allocating heap memory for it.
 */
BST::node_t *BST::insert (BST::node_t *cur_root, int val)
{
     if (tree == NULL)  /* you must assign 1st node to tree */
        return (tree = newNode(val));

     if (cur_root == NULL)
        return (cur_root = newNode(val));

     if (val <= cur_root->val )
         cur_root->left = insert (cur_root->left, val);
     else if (val > cur_root->val)
         cur_root->right = insert (cur_root->right, val);

     return cur_root;
}

/* determine whether node with value exists in tree
 * (don't swap parameter order -- it's confusing)
 */
BST::node_t *BST::find_node (BST::node_t *root, int val)
{
    if (root == NULL || root->val == val)
        return root;
    else if (root->val <= val) { 
        return find_node (root->left, val);
    }
    else
        return find_node (root->right, val);

    return root;
}

/* determine maximum value in the tree */
BST::node_t* BST::find_max (BST::node_t* root)
{
    if (root ==  NULL)
        return NULL;

    while (root->right != NULL)
        root = root->right;

    return root;
}

/* Deletes node and reorders bst */
BST::node_t* BST::delete_node (BST::node_t* root, int val)   
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return root;
    else if (val <= root->val)
        root->left = delete_node (root->left, val);
    else if (val > root->val)
        root->right = delete_node (root->right, val);
    else {
        // No child
        if (root->right == NULL && root->left == NULL) {
            delete root;
            root = NULL;
        }
        // One child
        else if (root->right == NULL) {
            node_t *temp = root;
            root = root->left;
            delete temp;
        }
        else if (root->left == NULL) {
            node_t *temp = root;
            root = root->right;
            delete temp;
        }
        // Two child
        else {
            node_t *temp = find_max (root->left);
            root->val = temp->val;
            root->left = delete_node (root->left, temp->val);
        }
    }
    return root;
}

/* Given a pointer to the root, frees the memory associated with 
 * an entire tree.
 */
void BST::delete_bst (BST::node_t *root)
{
    if (root != NULL) {
        delete_bst (root->left);
        delete_bst (root->right);
        delete(root);
    }

    tree = NULL;
}

/* Given a pointer to the root, prints all of
 * the values in a tree.
 */
void BST::print_bst (BST::node_t *root) 
{
    if (root != NULL) {
        printf ("%d ", root->val);
        print_bst (root->left);
        print_bst (root->right);
    }
}

int main (void) {

    BST bst;
    array<int, 9> ai = {17, 9, 23, 5, 11, 21, 27, 20, 22};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ai.size(); i++)
        bst.insert (bst.get_root(), ai[i]);

    bst.print_tree();   /* POSIX comliant output w/final '\n'
                         * use wrapper function, or just putchar('\n') here
                         */    
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arr_bst
17 9 5 11 23 21 20 22 27
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/arr_bst
==8123== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8123== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8123== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8123== Command: ./bin/arr_bst
==8123==
17 9 5 11 23 21 20 22 27
==8123==
==8123== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8123==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8123==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 10 frees, 72,920 bytes allocated
==8123==
==8123== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8123==
==8123== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8123== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fixed the insert and print function,

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

/*
 * Define a node structure for double linked list.
 */
class BST 
{
private:
    typedef struct node {
        int val;
        struct node* left;
        struct node* right;
    } node_t;
    node_t* tree;

public:
    BST() { tree = NULL; }
    node_t* newNode(int val);
    node_t* insert(node_t *&cur_root, int val);
    node_t* find_node(int val, node_t* root);
    node_t* find_val(int val, node_t* root);
    node_t* delete_node(int val, node_t* root);
    void delete_bst(node_t* root);
    void print_bst(node_t* root);
    node_t* find_max(node_t* root);

    node_t *bstroot;
};

// Creates a new node from a given value, allocating heap memory 
// for it.
BST::node_t* BST::newNode(int val)
{
    node_t* newNode = new node;
    newNode->val = val;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

// Inserts a new value into a given binary search tree, 
// allocating heap memory for it.
BST::node_t* BST::insert(BST::node_t *&cur_root, int val)
{
     if(cur_root == NULL) { 
        cur_root = newNode(val); 
     }

     else if( val <= cur_root->val )
         cur_root->left = insert(cur_root->left, val);
     else if( val > cur_root->val)
         cur_root->right = insert(cur_root->right, val);
     return cur_root;
}

void BST::print_bst(BST::node_t* root) 
{   
    if (root != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", root->val);
        print_bst(root->left);
        print_bst(root->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    BST bst;
    array<int, 9> ai = {17, 9, 23, 5, 11, 21, 27, 20, 22};
    for( size_t i = 0; i < ai.size(); ++i)
    {
        bst.insert(bst.bstroot, ai[i]);
    }
    bst.print_bst(bst.bstroot);
}
```